# Why do some parameters not appear in the matrix equation for an ANOVA model?

Tags: anova, matrix, notation

Here is the question I have been working on

[image: Question about two-way ANOVA]

and this is the answer of it

[image: Matrix equation for two-way ANOVA model]

I realised $\beta_3$ is not in the $\beta$ matrix. I don't understand why. Can anyone please explain this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$a_2$ is not there either.  That is because their values are determined by the others: $\alpha_2 = - \alpha_1$ and $\beta_3=-\beta_1-\beta_2$.

There seem to be some details missing from your question, but looking at ${X}$,

- the first row corresponds to $j=1, k=1$,
- the second to $j=1, k=2$,
- the third to $j=1, k=3$ ($\beta_3$ is implicitly flagged here by the $-1$s),
- the fourth to $j=2, k=1$,
- the fifth to $j=2, k=2$,
- the sixth to $j=2, k=3$ (again).